# Galaxy S3 Providing Audible Voicemail Notifications and Alarm reads the time out loud

Tags: notifications, alarm, text-to-speech

My Galaxy S3 just started notifying me of voicemails by stating out loud that I had a new voicemail. In addition, the alarm now states the time out loud as it plays the normal alarm music.

I have checked and the Driving Mode is turned OFF and the alarm is set for melody.

I receive no voice alerts for new emails, texts or incoming calls.

Please advise.

Comment: @AlEverett The solution in the question you linked was to turn off driving mode. The OP says he has already checked that it is off in this case.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same on my galaxy 4. Eventually I called AT&T and they fixed it on their end.

Comment: Did they say if the phone (hardware) was defective? Or was it software-related?